# Why does browser block popup windows in safari mobile in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, safari, mobile-safari

I'm trying to open a new window using following code:

`this.layoutService.url(order,this.testMethod()).subscribe( response => { window.open(encodeURI(response), '_blank');} );`

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEoVU.png)

*This site is attempting to open pop-up window*

Even I have set the block pop-up option to false still it is populating confirmation popup

Comment: All the navigators have the function to block pop-up. It's a choice of the client, you cannot avoid it.

Comment: I have set the block pop-up option to false still it is populating confirmation popup